# Is there a way to select one url among multiple picture urls with "exists" condition in laravel?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I have several picture urls some of them  may exists in the table, some of them may not. Columns are "picture, picture_thubnail, company_logo_thumbnail, company_logo". I want to select picture thumbnail as lets say "picture_url". But if "picture_thumbnail" does not exists, I want to pick "picture" as "picture_url". If "picture" does not exists I want to pick company_logo_thumbnail and so on... as a result I will get a picture_url as a string or null.

edit: this should be done in a single query instead of multiple queries with if else. or more elegant solutions are appretiated.

Comment: [Laravel Jetsream](https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/features/profile-management.html#profile-photos) has this out the box. Maybe read the source code to see how they do it. Until then, please can you provide some more detail to this question as it is very vague.

Comment: public function getProfilePhotoUrlAttribute()
    {
        return $this->profile_photo_path
                    ? Storage::disk($this->profilePhotoDisk())->url($this->profile_photo_path)
                    : $this->defaultProfilePhotoUrl();
    } @JustCarty you mean this? This is not looks like an answer to my question.
And i don't know how can i be more clear. Could you ask which part you don't understand sir

Answer (score 1):

Sounds more like a database thing than a Laravel thing (the easiest way I can think of anyway).

```
$images = DB::table('images')
    ->select(DB::raw('COALESCE(picture_thumbnail, picture, company_logo_thumbnail, company_logo) as picture_url'))
    ->get();
```

The MySQL [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function returns the first non-null result.

This is also assuming that you are using MySQL as your database engine.

**UPDATE**

To check a column in another table you could use a join.

```
$images = DB::table('images')
    ->select(DB::raw('COALESCE(picture_thumbnail, picture, company_logo_thumbnail, company_logo, company_logos.id) as picture_url'))
    ->leftJoin('company_logos', 'company_logos.id', '=', 'images.company_logo_id')
    ->get();
```

I've used `company_logos.id` in the select, but guessing it would be something like `company_logos.picture` or something with the filename, rather than the id of the row.

**UPDATE 2**

I would change this to be a left join:

```
->join('cloudfiles', function ($join) {
        $join->on('userdetails.company_logo_id', '=', 'cloudfiles.id')->where('company_logo_id', '!=', null);
    })
```

```
->leftJoin('cloudfiles', function ($join) {
        $join->on('userdetails.company_logo_id', '=', 'cloudfiles.id')->where('company_logo_id', '!=', null);
    })
```

A left join would mean you still get all results from the `userdetails` where as a normal join would mean only `userdetails` that have an associated `cloudfiles` record would be returned.

Secondly, I'd change this:

```
->where('company_logo_id', '!=', null)
```

to

```
->whereNotNull('company_logo_id')
```

Although I think you might be able to remove that condition completely.

Couple of other points, just fyi:

```
$boothOwner = Booth::where('id', '=', Request()->booth_id)->firstOrFail();
```

could be (unless there are somehow duplicate ids in the table)

```
$boothOwner = Booth::findOrFail(Request()->booth_id);
```

Similarly,

```
->whereRaw('userdetails.user_id = ?', [$boothOwner->user_id])
```

could be

```
->where('userdetails.user_id', $boothOwner->user_id)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. its working. Another question is actually i have company_logo_id instead of company_logo. how can i get it with relation @martincarlin87

Comment: @baytencere assuming `company_logo_id` is `NULL` or an integer you could add it to the list of columns that are in the `COALESCE` and it should work the same. If you want to actually check, you could add a join, I will update the answer.

Comment: ok but when i try it with a join, it returns empty array instead of NULL. and it breaks the COALESCE chain at the beginning

Comment: $boothOwner = Booth::where('id', '=', Request()->booth_id)->firstOrFail();
            return DB::table('userdetails')
            ->whereRaw('userdetails.user_id = ?', [$boothOwner->user_id])
            ->join('cloudfiles', function ($join) {
                $join->on('userdetails.company_logo_id', '=', 'cloudfiles.id')->where('company_logo_id', '!=', null);
            })
            ->select(DB::raw('COALESCE(cloudfiles.thumbnail, cloudfiles.file_url, userdetails.thumbnail, userdetails.picture) as picture_url'))
            ->get()->pluck('picture_url')[0];

Comment: btw db is postgresql

Comment: cool, I haven't used postgres, but have noticed a couple of things, will update the answer.

Comment: excellent, glad to hear it works, no problem at all!